# How to identify all AVR MCUs (ATtiny and ATmega) that feature a factory-programmed unique ID

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

On Microchip's site, the "parametric search" table for microcontrollers does not have a filter column to select the models that feature a unique ID.  Is there a way to list (enumerate) all models that have this feature?

For example, I saw that the ATtiny416 does have it.  However, this model is not supported on the avr-gcc toolchain on Linux (at least not the version I have, with Ubuntu 22.04); hence my motivation for this question.

Is there some particular keyword(s) that I could search inside the .h files, say, `/usr/lib/avr/include/avr/io*.h` that would reveal which ones among those supported models feature the unique ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You access serial number using `SERNUMx` register, so searching for `SERNUM0` should give you the results you want:

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aavrdudes%2Favr-libc%20SERNUM0&type=code

or if you want to see the list locally:

```
git clone https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc
cd avr-libc/
git grep -l SERNUM '*.h'
```

this returns 80 entries currently, such as avr128da28, "iom1608" (meaning "atmega1608"), "iotn212" (meaning atttiny212) etc...

(also, if you want newer avr-gcc you can use 3rd-party embedded managers like "platformio".)

Comment: I had thought of the SERNUM (which I had seen on the tiny416 datasheet), but this command: `grep -i -r sernum /usr/lib/avr/include` returns nothing (is it possible that _none_ of the models with SERNUM happen to be among the supported models in avr-gcc 5.4.0 ??).  Also, I cannot execute that github command, since it requires me to log in to my account; I don't have a github account (never have had, not really willing to create one). Could you post the output that your example search produces?

Comment: There are 80 matching chips, I think this is too much to copy-paste into answer. But I've added command-line version which does not require any logins. Also, this is not in avr-gcc but rather in avr-libc; and my version on ubuntu 20.04 supports none of those chips.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the tiny416/816 *is* among the matching items!  I suppose that I can simply merge this contents with my `apt`-installed `avr-gcc`, simply copy these `.h` files?  I'm used to simply worry about adding a line in the Makefile, example: `MCU=atmega328p`, and that is copied into some command-line arguments; not sure whether I need to do anything extra to make it work with an "imported" header file?  (I guess I will soon find out)